# 'Date.parse("05/11/19")' parses in YY/MM/DD?

Tags: ruby, date

I have a date in string format `"05/11/19"` I used `Date.parse`, but when I use `strftime("%d %b %Y")`, it parsed the date as 19 Nov 2005. Is there another way to parse my string to date without messing up the day and year fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a format String when parsing:

```
require 'date'

datestring = '05/11/19' # 05 Nov 2019
date = Date.strptime(datestring, '%d/%m/%y')
puts date.strftime('%d %b %Y') # => 05 Nov 2019
```